# Dividing float point data in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a data file (input.dat) in two columns, something like this

```
 5.12  .5
 4.1   93.8 
.9     11.2
.58    5.3
```

and I want to add a constant (for example 5.3) to second column values.

I did awk '{print $1, $2 + 5.3 }' < input.dat > output.dat

and it worked perfectly, output.dat looked as

```
 5.12  5.8
 4.1   99.1 
 .9    16.5
 .58   10.6
```

but when I said a=5.3 and did:

awk '{print $1, $2 + $a }' < input.dat > output.dat

something completely crazy happened to output.dat:

```
5.12  5.62
4.1   97.9 
.9     12.1
.58    5.88
```

Can someone please tell me what happened, I assume the problem was with the print which only expects $1, $2, $3 etc. 
I think the solution to my problem is possible if I write variable a in third column of input.dat file and then do awk '{ print $1, $2+$3 }, but what is the proper way to do floating point arithmetic operations on columns in bash?

Comment: You have to learn the difference between shell and awk - they are 2 completely different tools. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks, I just started using bash, and I managed to write couple of neat scripts for analysis of my data but I always struggle with usage of sed/grep/awk/cut when I want to solve something.

Comment: But those are precisely THE tools you need to use to analyse data, especially awk (if you know awk then you don't need the others) so if you've written a couple of neat scripts without knowing how to use those tools then it's like building a neat house without knowing how to use a hammer, saw, and screwdriver - you might make **something** to keep the rain off but it's going to have some issues! If you've written any shell loops as part of your neat scripts then see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do

```
awk -v a=5 '{print $1,$2+a}' input.dat
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, although my variable depends on other variables, but I did this:

awk -v a=$a '{print $1,$2+a}' input.dat

and I could declare variable anywhere else.